# create pipeline for image processing

Tags: image-processing, pipeline, luigi

I'm working on some image processing steps that are quite simple. 
Here are the steps:

1. Download images from aws s3 for specific id
2. Reformat images from gif or whatever to jpg
3. Check images size
4. Resize images if possible (just was thinking of it:upsample/downsample images - not sure yet if that step is coming)
5. classify images and update database information
6. get next id and repeat 1.

If I had to implement it fast without thinking I would just write a simple python script with subfunctions for each step (and throw exception if something goes wrong - some steps are nice to have like (4.) others steps like (5.) are necessary).

I heard about luigi and pipelining and was wondering if that would be a use case.

What would be the benefits using something like luigi or maybe something else - is there a best practice for the problem that I try to deal with?

To give you some numbers right now I have about 20gb Data and more then 100k images. Every day there about 10k+ images that have to be processed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using EC2 instances, it makes sense to use a workflow orchestration framework such as luigi and pipelining.

However there is a better approach you can utilize in AWS, using Lambda and [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/). Here you can design the event driven workflow with image transformation logic in each steps while step functions manage the state machine with visualization, which is inherently scalable.

Your can design the event driven flow as follows.

***Upload image  to S3 -> trigger step functions workflow-> Write back to S3***.

Comment: Actually my main application is on Digital Ocean and I'm using S3 for image hosting. I also was thinking if something like Lambda would be a usecase. but I'm no familiar with it. Is it possible to use in Lambda something like tensorflow and my own python scripts and packages? Is it a good Idea if I have to care about costs? For Digital Ocean I'm paying 5$ / month and I think I would need about few seconds for each image.

Comment: You can use Lambda with your own python packages for image processing. Infact there are prebuilt templates also for create image thumbnails. The cost model is different compared to the model in digital ocean where you will pay for Lambda execution time in seconds so more of a opex cost than upfront cost where the cost increases with usage. Here if the scripts and steps are minimal you can only use Lambda only. For complex workflows I would prefer step functions with Lambda where there will be an additional cost for step transition.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will take a look on lambda but still not 100% sure which way to go.